# How to exclude lines from test coverage in TestNG?

Tags: unit-testing, intellij-idea

I have some classes and packages that I want to exclude from test coverage. I am using IntelliJ Idea and I've added the following configurations. The exluded tests do not run but my coverage is dropped. How can I exluded those packages from calculation of the coverage?

Thank you

```
<test name="PackageTests">
    <packages>
        <package name="com.company.package.*">
            <exclude name="com.company.package.config.*"></exclude>
            <exclude name="com.company.package.service.*"></exclude>
        </package>
    </packages>
</test>
```

Comment: AFAIK there is no such feature. Feel  free to create feature request on YouTrack: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.

Comment: Is it possible to do it in Jacoco plugin?